# HTML5 audio won't play on other devices, or any device without the audio already predownloaded on it it

Tags: html, hyperlink, download, html5-audio

I am creating an audio file for a school project using HTML5, but when I try to play the audio file on another device/site, it doesn't play. I realized that it wasn't playing because it can't find the audio file a device or site that doesn't already have it downloaded. How can I fix this, so any device can play the audio? I posted a picture of the audio file showing nothing to play.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h3>Playboi Carti Beat</h3>
<audio controls="controls" controls="download"> <br>
  <source src="carti.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
<source src="carti.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /><br>
</audio>
<br>
<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=13zEuFOMt57KsSmz7UE5lwDcIt2eRHyea"</a>
<br>
    <button>Download Audio</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I wanted a playable audio file on any device, instead the audio will only play on devices and sites that already have it downloaded, if they don't then it won't play.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and the validator reports 16 errors and warnings. You should delete this question, fix your errors, and then come back if you still have issues.